# how to implement a uicollectionview that has multiple sections and subsections?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewflowlayout

The uicollectionview has n sections (say 1,2,3) that has m subsections (say 1.1,1.2 etc) which further branches into inner subsections (1.1.1, 1.1.2 etc) which finally has X no. of rows in it.

[image: Like the layout in this picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented this using UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. Used the
`UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { [self] (sectionNumber, environment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in .... }`  closure to setup the layout items and group them vertically and horizontally to form the layout for the entire section.

For reference -

To create an individual **item** (H: 50, W: 50)  -

```
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(50), heightDimension: .absolute(50)))
```

To create **groups (Horizontal)** -

```
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize:
                                                                    NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension:
                                                                            .absolute(item.layoutSize.widthDimension.dimension * CGFloat((data.count))),
                                                                                           heightDimension:  .estimated(50)), subitem: item, count: (data.count))
```

**Group - vertical**

```
 let subGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize:
                                                            NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension:
                                                                    .absolute(CGFloat(width)),
                                                                                   heightDimension:
                                                                    .absolute(heightForIndividualItem * CGFloat(data.count))),
                                                        subitems: group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use three collection views and three screens?

Tap on `Section 1` creates second screen with collection view with sections `Subsection 1` and `Subsection 2`.

Then tap on `Subsection 1` creates third screen with collection view with sections `Row 1`, `Row 1`, `Row 1`, `Row 1`.

Comment: No there should be no animations involved except horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Comment: @Dracarys If you need animations, then consider [new API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views): compositional layout and diffable datasource.